# USB hub not recognized after boot

Tags: linux, usb, usb-hub

I have a laptop with only 2 USB-A sockets, which is a bit too few when I want to use it with an external mouse and keyboard at my desk *and* also sometimes transfer files to/from a phone or a flash stick.

So I bought a cheap 4-port USB hub to use as a "poor man's docking station" at the desk, letting the mouse and keyboard share a single port.

This works fine, *except* that if the hug is plugged in when I boot up the laptop (Ubuntu 18.04) there's about a 50/50 chance that the hub will not be recognized: Its power LED lights up, but neither mouse nor keyboard works at the login screen. It starts working if I unplug it for 3-4 seconds, but not if I replug it too soon.

**Question:** Is this something I just have to live with, perhaps the fault of the OS that would be the same with any hub? Or does it sound like the hub I bought is a lemon, and picking a more expensive hub might yield better results?

Comment: Someone has voted to close as "opinion-based". To be clear, I'm looking for **experience/knowledge-based** answers (since I don't know enough details of the USB protocol, host controller interfaces, and the Linux driver architecture in general to know which explanation would make technical sense), not opinions.

Comment: @karel: Shouldn't a plain USB hub _just work_ on the protocol level without requiring specific drivers on the host device? `lsusb` seems to indicate that there are already hubs in the laptop's USB topology _internally_.